# Does Maintenance Mode Disable Scheduler on Heroku

Tags: heroku

Does maintenance mode turn off scheduler? If not does a way exist to temporarily disable scheduler without manually deleting every item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope. The only thing maintenance mode does is tell the router to refuse to forward new web requests. Everything else still runs, including one-off dynos (which the scheduler uses): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode

One way to work around this would be to have your scheduled tasks just enqueue a job in a delayed job processing system (like delayed_job or resque). That way, you can scale the worker dynos down to 0 and nothing serious should happen during downtime, instead of the database or external services accidentally being written to.

Comment: Note that creating delayed jobs does write to the database, which can be a problem if your downtime is database-related.

Answer (score 14):

I recently ran into the issue of not being able to pause or disable the Heroku scheduler as well. I needed to do a DB upgrade so I couldn't use the delayed job suggestion. Not finding a better solution I wrote a little disable rake task.

```
task :pause_scheduler => :environment do
  if ENV['PAUSE_SCHEDULER'] == 'true'
    puts 'Scheduler Paused'
    exit
  end
end
```

Then I just inherit from `:pause_scheduler` instead of from `:environment` for all of my Heroku scheduler cron jobs and set the PAUSE_SCHEDULER environment variable to 'true' when I want to turn it off.

```
heroku config:set PAUSE_SCHEDULER=true
```

Seems to work pretty well. Much better than deleting and recreating all my scheduled jobs at any rate.

Just remember to turn it back on after you're done.

```
heroku config:set PAUSE_SCHEDULER=false
```

Hope that helps!